# updating model in try/catch : model remembers faulty update values in the catch

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, exception

i have a nested function calls to update some data in database , the column im going to update is unique in database and it may be updated with a duplicate value in that case i want to flag that model/row as duplicated

here is simplified version of my code without the nested function calls

```
public $defaultModel ;


function errorTest(){
    $this->defaultModel = $inprogress = Process::where('inprogress' , 1 )->first();
    try
    {
        $inprogress->update( [
            'deployment_id' => 666 ,
        ]);

    }
    catch (\Exception $exception)
    {
        $this->defaultModel->update([
            'inprogress' => 0  ,
            'error'=>'duplicate'
        ]);
    }
}
```

when i try to update the model with a duplicate value i keep getting laravel error page

```
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '666' for key 
  'process_deployment_id_unique'
```

at first i thought maybe my try/catch isnt working and i cant catch the error , but after playing around i found out the error is caused by catch section

```
        $this->defaultModel->update([
            'inprogress' => 0  ,
            'error'=>'duplicate'
        ]);
```

even though im not updating the unique column `(deployment_id)` in the catch , the model is still remembering the value given in the try body and trying to update  `deployment_id` in the catch with the `666` value

crazy part is im not even using the same variable in the catch section ! it's like they are referencing each other

the only way around it is to do something like

```
        $model = $this->defaultModel->fresh();
        $model->update([
            'inprogress' => 0  ,
            'error'=>'duplicate'
        ]);
```

any idea why is this happening ?

**please dont suggest another approach or method , i know i can use a different methods ....  my question is about model remembering try data on catch update**

Comment: Use transaction commit rollback ... it will be easy for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Model::update()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/3b2bdc2cb762662bc0a2d1745777056e51bc6d71/Eloquent/Model.php#L989) method is implemented like this:

```
return $this->fill($attributes)->save($options);
```

It means that the model object is updated first, *then* saved to the database. In case the SQL query fails, the model keeps the new values and they are still considered dirty (i.e. not synced with the database).

If you call `update()` on the same model again, Eloquent will try to save all the dirty attributes (which, in your case, includes `deployment_id`).

Note that, in your code, `$this->defaultModel` and `$inprogress` refer to the same model object, so using one or the other will have the same effect.

Comment: Can you please provide the source which states the they are marked dirty? Your explanation isn't entirely accurate. It does not mark any attributes as dirty, if the SQL query fails, the model object remains unchanged.

Comment: @Adi The model keeps the original values in [`$original`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/3b2bdc2cb762662bc0a2d1745777056e51bc6d71/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L59) and the current ones in [`$attributes`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/3b2bdc2cb762662bc0a2d1745777056e51bc6d71/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L52). An attribute is dirty when its original and current values are different. When `save()` succeeds, it calls `finishSave()`, which calls `syncOriginal()`, which copies `$attributes` to `$original`; as a result, the model is not dirty anymore.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, so do you mean `$this->defaultModel->fresh()` or similar reload, can be used as well?

Comment: @Adi `fresh()` will return a new model object loaded from the database; that object won't be dirty (if that's your question).

Answer (score 1):

So the variables scope in PHP is by function and not by per block. So when you assign a variable inside the try block, you can access it outside also, so long as they're in the same function. Which is why you are seeing the same value in catch block.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your approach, first check if that ID exists within the database table, if yes you can mark that entry as duplicate, if no you can update that column value with your ID.

Comment: thanx i know that , but thats not my question  
read about race condition , your approach is prone to bug